# Do you want to play again

Tags: c++

Help I have no idea as to where to put the "Do you want to play again" command, I have tried a few variations myself and I have hit a brick wall my game works as it is but I want the extra marks available for completing the game and offering the chance to play again?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>       //ensures that the system clock is set

void main()
{
char player1[10];
srand(time(NULL));              //this command is only required at the start and sets the clock

printf("Please enter your name? - ");
scanf("%s", player1);           //this command is used to store the players name for us later on within the game
printf("\n\n");

//The following printf commands issue the rules of the game and ensure that they are printed and viewable
printf("Welcome %s to the Pairs (Matching Game)\n\n", player1);
printf("The rules of the game are as follows\n\n");
printf(" 1. The player should enter a location of card 1 and card 2\n\n");
printf(" 2. The player should only use a numeric format to enter the\n    location of the card i.e. 11 and 44 this would show only\n    Line 1 box 1 and line 4 box 4\n\n");
printf(" 3. Should the player enter a location outside of the table\n    range 'You have incorrectly selected a location, please\n    try again' will be displayed\n\n");
printf(" 4. A player should select 2 cards to be shown if they match\n    the cards are removed\n\n");
printf(" 5. If a player selects a non matching pair 'Please try again\n    - you've selected an non matching pair' should be displayed\n\n");
printf(" 6. The object of the game is to match all the pairs in the \n    least amount of turns possible\n\n");
printf(" 7. The player cannot use any symbol !£$%^&*@~? as these will\n    not be recognised by the game and cause it to freeze resulting\n    in a restarted game\n");

printf("\n");

char ag = 'y' || 'Y';
do {
    char grid[17] = { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h' };     //sets the characters used in the grid
    int high = 15;
    int random, random2, temp, card1, card2;
    int low = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int flag = 0;           //this variable is used to identify potential issues
    int turns = 0;      //identifies the variable for the amount of turns taken

    for (x = 1; x < 100; x++)           //sets the random loop to vary the selection 100 times prior to selecting a game table
    {
        random = rand() % (high - low + 1) + low;
        random2 = rand() % (high - low + 1) + low;
        temp = grid[random];
        grid[random] = grid[random2];
        grid[random2] = temp;
    }

    while ((grid[0] != 'x') || (grid[1] != 'x') || (grid[2] != 'x') || (grid[3] != 'x') || (grid[4] != 'x') || (grid[5] != 'x') || (grid[6] != 'x') || (grid[7] != 'x') || (grid[8] != 'x') || (grid[9] != 'x') || (grid[10] != 'x') || (grid[11] != 'x') || (grid[12] != 'x') || (grid[13] != 'x') || (grid[14] != 'x') || (grid[15] != 'x'))
    {

        for (x = 0; x < 16; x++)
        {
            counter++;
            printf("| %c ", grid[x]);   //The grid is shown using this command for testing purposes only must be removed prior to playing

            if (counter == 4)
            {
                printf("\n");
                counter = 0;
            }

        }

        printf("\n");
        printf(" Please enter Card 1 : ");  //Enter the location of your first card
        scanf_s("%d", &card1);              //Displays your first card
        printf(" Please enter Card 2 : ");  //Enter the location of your next card
        scanf_s("%d", &card2);              //Displays your second card
        printf("");
        turns = turns + 1;                  //the turns variable has been set to count every attempt at matching cards

        if (card1 == 11)                    //This sets the array (location) for card 1
        {
            card1 = 0;
        }
        else if (card1 == 12)
        {
            card1 = 1;
        }
        else if (card1 == 13)
        {
            card1 = 2;
        }
        else if (card1 == 14)
        {
            card1 = 3;
        }
        else if (card1 == 21)
        {
            card1 = 4;
        }
        else if (card1 == 22)
        {
            card1 = 5;
        }
        else if (card1 == 23)
        {
            card1 = 6;
        }
        else if (card1 == 24)
        {
            card1 = 7;
        }
        else if (card1 == 31)
        {
            card1 = 8;
        }
        else if (card1 == 32)
        {
            card1 = 9;
        }
        else if (card1 == 33)
        {
            card1 = 10;
        }
        else if (card1 == 34)
        {
            card1 = 11;
        }
        else if (card1 == 41)
        {
            card1 = 12;
        }
        else if (card1 == 42)
        {
            card1 = 13;
        }
        else if (card1 == 43)
        {
            card1 = 14;
        }
        else if (card1 == 44)
        {
            card1 = 15;
        }
        else
        {
            card1 = -1;
        }

        if (card2 == 11)                            // This will set the arrays (location) for card2
        {
            card2 = 0;
        }
        else if (card2 == 12)
        {
            card2 = 1;
        }
        else if (card2 == 13)
        {
            card2 = 2;
        }
        else if (card2 == 14)
        {
            card2 = 3;
        }
        else if (card2 == 21)
        {
            card2 = 4;
        }
        else if (card2 == 22)
        {
            card2 = 5;
        }
        else if (card2 == 23)
        {
            card2 = 6;
        }
        else if (card2 == 24)
        {
            card2 = 7;
        }
        else if (card2 == 31)
        {
            card2 = 8;
        }
        else if (card2 == 32)
        {
            card2 = 9;
        }
        else if (card2 == 33)
        {
            card2 = 10;
        }
        else if (card2 == 34)
        {
            card2 = 11;
        }
        else if (card2 == 41)
        {
            card2 = 12;
        }
        else if (card2 == 42)
        {
            card2 = 13;
        }
        else if (card2 == 43)
        {
            card2 = 14;
        }
        else if (card2 == 44)
        {
            card2 = 15;
        }
        else
        {
            card2 = -1;
        }
        printf("\n\nCARD 1: %d\n", card1);      //printf shows the location of the card selected from 0 to 15
        printf("CARD 2: %d\n\n", card2);        //printf shows the location of the card selected from 0 to 15

        if (((card1 < 0) || (card1>15)) || ((card2 < 0) || (card2>15)))
        {
            printf("\nYou have incorrectly selected a location, please try again\n\n");
            flag = 1;
            printf("Flag=%d\n", flag);      //This printf command is just for testing remove prior to playing the game
        }

        counter = 0;                        //This resets the counter

        for (x = 0; x < 16; x++)        // this means it will only loop the count 16 times
        {
            counter++;      // this will add 1 to the counter
            printf("|   ");

            if (card1 == x)
            {
                printf("%c", grid[card1]);
            }
            else if (card2 == x)
            {
                printf("%c", grid[card2]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            if (counter > 3)
            {
                printf("\n");
                counter = 0;    // This will reset the counter back to zero 

            }
        }
        if ((grid[card1] == 'x') || (grid[card2] == 'x'))       //This 'if statment' states if you have made the choice 
        {
            printf("\nUnfortunately you have selected a card already match, please try again\n\n");
        }
        if ((grid[card1] == grid[card2]) && (grid[card1] != 'x') && (grid[card2] != 'x') && (flag == 0)) //This is the 'if statment' that will match the pairs and then mark them as 'x' 
        {
            printf("\nCongratulations you have found a pair!!\n");
            grid[card1] = 'x';
            grid[card2] = 'x';
        }

        if (((grid[card1] != grid[card2]) && (grid[card1] != 'x') && (grid[card2] != 'x')) && (flag == 0)) //This 'if statment' states if the guesses are incorrect
        {
            printf("\nOopps remember the cards as you need to try again\n\n");
        }
        }
        printf("\nExcellent %s you have managed to match all the cards correctly in %d turns\n\n", player1, turns);
        printf("Do you want to play again? (y/n)\n\n");
        scanf_s(" %c", &ag);
        printf("\n\n");
```

} while (ag == 'n' || ag == 'N'); //This is the exit statement from the program and ensures that the game can be played on if 'Y' is selected
    printf("\n\nThanks for playing see you again sometime for another \nthrilling game of Matching Pairs!!!\n\n");
}

Comment: I regret to inform you that it looks like you are actually programming in C, not C++.

Comment: I would also think at the end. Also, your code could seriously benefit from switch case statements. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html

Comment: Can't spot any C++ here I'm afraid

Comment: @mapierce271: It's C++, though C-style. The MSisms are a giveaway.

Comment: Just realised my obvious error yes I am using C we have not covered switch statements as yet at Uni, any advice on the how as I am going mad trying to work it out? @mapierce271

Comment: @SimonDownes: `main` returns `int` in C and C++. Also, are you *sure* that's C++, as you use the MS-compiler? BTW: Do you know `<` `>` and `&&`, as well as `-`? Should save lots of typing.

Comment: We are using C++ and we were told it would be in the style of C, I have managed to get so far but I just cant seem to get the loop right for how to play again, as I have only been doing this for 8 weeks I am pleased so far @Deduplicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to wrap your execution part (that you will repeat in every new game before user decides to quit the game) in the do-while loop (that is executed at least once and checks postcondition):

```
        char ag = '';
        do {
            char grid[17] = { 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h'         };     //sets the characters used in the grid
            int again = 0;
            int high = 15;
            int low = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int flag = 0;           //this variable is used to identify potential issues
            int turns = 0;      //identifies the variable for the amount of turns taken
            for (x = 1; x < 100; x++)           //sets the random loop to vary the selection 100 times prior to selecting a game table
            ...
            printf("\nExcellent %s you have managed to match all the cards correctly in %d turns\n\n", player1, turns);
            printf("Do you want to play again? (y/n)");
            scanf(" %c", &ag);
        } while (ag=='y' || ag=='Y');
    }
```

EDIT

Not only `y`, but also `Y` restarts the game.

Varible initializations placed inside `do-while` loop.

Comment: Hi @striving_coder I have implemented your code however after the }while (ag=='y'); how does it repeat?

Comment: @SimonDownes: Body of the cycle (everything between `do` and `while`) will be executed first time no matter what. When the execution reaches the `while`, it evaluates condition (whether `ag` is equal to `'y'` in this case), and if it's true the body of cycle is repeated again (i.e. execution transfers from `while` back to the  `for (x = 1; x < 100; x++)` part). And so it continues until user enters something other than "y" for the last question. Makes sense?

Comment: I have now implemented the code within the program and I'm still having issues not sure as to why, I have used your exact coding etc. @striving_coder

Comment: @SimonDownes: What kind of issues are you having? Please be more specific.

Comment: I can play the game through to the end and it then crashes asking me to debug? If I say no it then ends the game its displays everthing correctly however I cannot enter either y or n @striving_coder

Comment: @SimonDownes: What kind of error message does it give you? And what happens if you agree to debug?

Comment: So looking at the code again I noticed that I had incorrectly copied the code over, so I have now played again it allows me to enter N that ends the game however when I use Y it doesn't repeat the game? @striving_coder

Comment: I have uploaded the coding again to see if I have done anything incorrect? @striving_coder

Comment: @SimonDownes: In the previous version only y (not Y) restarted the game. I fixed it now (see updated answer). Also, initialization of most of the variables should be placed inside the `do-while` loop body, because these variables need to be reset after each game. (Obviously, these initializations should also be removed from the top of the code where they were before.) Notice that I used 0 as default initialization value of `flag` - make sure it's correct.

Comment: Well I can rest easy as I have now with @striving_coder assistance completed the game now to move onto my report and a large thank you to all who assisted